# Unable to debug in an event receiver sharepoint 2010

Tags: visual-studio, user-profile, sharepoint-enterprise, debugging, event-receivers

When i debug in the event reciever(item adding) as soon as it reached the if condition 
i get the following error

> unable to automatically step into the server.The remote procedure could not be debugged. This usually indicates that the 
>   debugging has not been enabled on the server.

```
 SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(Osite);
       UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);

       UserProfile u = upm.GetUserProfile(accNames);
       if (u[PropertyConstants.WorkEmail].ToString() != null || u[PropertyConstants.WorkEmail].ToString() != string.Empty)
       {
```

I am working on a remote machine in the dev environment..i also turn the the debug = false to true in webconfig file..but no luck..any suggestions?

Comment: when you say remote machine, is the debugger running on the same machine that the SharePoint server and User Profile Serview are executing on?

Comment: yes it is on the same machine

Comment: Although not answering your question, I am wondering if you could avoid using User Profile to get email address for a given account name. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms478576.aspx

Comment: I debugged it again ..when it was on if(u[PropertyConstants.WorkEmail].ToString() != .. condition it gave the error in the pop pup box i..so clicked ok, and then when i pressed f11 ..it did allow to again to debug through...i think its just the part when the code is getting information from the user profiles, it does not allow to debug